# Get ID of an <a> tag when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html

On my HTML page, I have different  tag with different ID. The idea is that, when I clicked to an `<a>` tag, I want to get the ID back.

My code looks like this:

```
<a id="id1"></a>
<a id="id2"></a>
<a id="id3"></a>
<a id="id4"></a>
<a id="id5"></a>
```

Comment: Aside: it looks like you should be using classes, not IDs.

Comment: What happen if I want to use id instead of class? Can I use it?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the the trick:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.id);
  });
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/jondlm/pen/BFEAm

Comment: I will try it and see how is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Register a click handler (I'll use inline for this) and pass `this` as a param:

```
<a id="id1" onclick="linkHandler(this)"></a>
<a id="id2" onclick="linkHandler(this)"></a>
<a id="id3" onclick="linkHandler(this)"></a>
<a id="id4" onclick="linkHandler(this)"></a>
<a id="id5" onclick="linkHandler(this)"></a>

function linkHandler(el) {
    console.log(el.id); //id of clicked element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:

```
<a id="id1" onClick="getMe(this);" href="#"></a>
<a id="id2" onClick="getMe(this);" href="#"></a>
<a id="id3" onClick="getMe(this);" href="#"></a>
<a id="id4" onClick="getMe(this);" href="#"></a>
<a id="id5" onClick="getMe(this);" href="#"></a>
```

...

```
<script>
function getMe(x)
{
    alert(x.id);
}
</script>
```